# Is there an equivalent of createQueryStream in BQ Java client to stream results like in NodeJS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I know that `createQueryStream` [exists](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/bigquery/dataset#_google_cloud_bigquery_Dataset_createQueryStream_member_1_) in NodeJS client library; which let's us stream output of a query as a stream. The problem is that, I can not find an equivalent of that for the Java client library. I need a way to stream query results data with my vert.x endpoint (I'll likely use SSE or websocket). So 1) Is there an equivalent of "createQueryStream" in Java client library? or 2) If not, how do I achieve "streaming" of BQ query results in Java?

Comment: Hi @scaryguy, Have you checked this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/streaming-data-into-bigquery#streaminginsertexamples) for Streaming data into BigQuery using Java ? Is this helpful for you ?

Comment: It is not helpful because the question is about *reading* data, not *inserting* data. There is Storage Read API but it doesn't work with materialized views so it doesn't work for me. My question is still applicable.

Comment: There is no Java client library to stream the results using \`createQueryStream\`  in the BigQuery. If you want this feature to be implemented, you can open a new [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) on the issue tracker.